# Xcode Error - NSException?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I receive this error when I try to open my view

> 2011-03-30 18:03:46.703
>   iDubstep[516:207] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for
>   the key timeimg.'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x0140bbe9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x012005c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>     2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0140bb21 -[NSException raise] + 17
>     3   Foundation
>
>   0x000476cf _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter +
>   135   4   Foundation
>
>   0x0004763d
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285  5   UIKit
>
>   0x004c68d6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection
>   connect] + 112    6   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x013822cf -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239    7 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x004c52ed -[UINib
>   instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
>     8   UIKit
>
>   0x004c7081
>   -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168    9 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x0037fa94 -[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70   10  UIKit
>
>   0x0037d709 -[UIViewController
>   loadView] + 120   11  UIKit
>
>   0x0037d5e3 -[UIViewController view] +
>   56    12  UIKit
>
>   0x0037f012 -[UIViewController
>   viewControllerForRotation] + 63   13 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x0037af76 -[UIViewController
>   _visibleView] + 90    14  UIKit                               0x00614a97 -[UIClientRotationContext
>   initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:]
>   + 354     15  UIKit                               0x002f6ba8 -[UIWindow
>   _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:]
>   + 954     16  UIKit                               0x00576948 -[UIWindowController
>   transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]
>   + 1053    17  UIKit                               0x00381982 -[UIViewController
>   presentModalViewController:withTransition:]
>   + 3151    18  iDubstep                            0x00007b34 -[MainerViewController
>   goRecord:] + 153  19  UIKit
>
>   0x002cfa6e -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
>     20  UIKit
>
>   0x0035e1b5 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     21 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x00360647 -[UIControl(Internal)
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527   22  UIKit
>
>   0x0035f438 -[UIControl
>   touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 277    23 
>   UIKit
>
>   0x002f4025 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395  24  UIKit
>
>   0x002d537a -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>   + 447     25  UIKit                               0x002da732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent +
>   7576  26  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x01c22a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>     27  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x013ed064
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  28  CoreFoundation                      0x0134d6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>     29  CoreFoundation
>   0x0134a983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   30 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x0134a240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     31  CoreFoundation
>   0x0134a161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    32
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x01c21268 GSEventRunModal + 217  33 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x01c2132d GSEventRun + 115   34  UIKit
>   0x002de42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     35  iDubstep
>   0x000028f8 main + 102     36  iDubstep
>   0x00002889 start + 53 ) terminate
>   called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

Comment: Please describe you problem better!

Answer (score 2):

Code is badly needed here...

In the mean time, the first line says what the error is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key timeimg.'
```

Just search your project for `forKey:@"timeimg"`. (Maybe you should replace that timeimg with a timeing or a timing.)

Answer (score 1):

I expect you wrote `timeing` somewhere where you meant to write `timing`.  But without code, it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're in the process of loading a nib file here. Is it possible that you fixed a misspelling in the name of one of your view controller's outlets? If you did that after connecting one or more objects to that outlet, the nib file probably still contains the original misspelling. Look in your view controller's nib for bad connections. If you can identify the problematic object, disconnect it from any outlets and reconnect.